# How to install windows and manjaro on a system that already has windows

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning, multi-boot, manjaro

Sorry that the title of this question may seem unclear, but I really couldn't think of how to phrase this well. Right now, I have a system that has only windows 8.1 (Embedded) on it. By the way, I have two drives: a 120gb ssd that windows is currently stored on, and a hard drive for general storage. I have already copied all of the files I care about from my windows installation to a hard drive. So, the way I was hoping that I could do this is have linux installed on my SSD, and having my hard drive partitioned so that one half is linked to the linux installation, and one half is a windows 10 installation. I don't quite know what I should do first. I already have a bootable manjaro USB, so what do I do next?

Answer (score 0):

**First of all I would backup all important files to an external hdd.**

1. Now you should upgrade to win10, because this installation could damage your running linux os.
2. In the next step you should disable fast boot in windows
3. Boot your live system and create the necessary partitions (root, home and swap)
4. Install your live system using the windows boot partition (maybe sda2) as boot partition in linux
5. Chroot in your newly installed linux and install efibootmgr and os-prober
6. Restore the grub configuration (the windows installation should now be found)
7. Have fun

It should work so, but I recommend to do a clean windows installation. You can create clean partitions without resizing them. Furthermore your windows works a bit better. You should install windows at first, because it destroys the dual boot configuration. Good luck. I assume no guarantee for the given information.

If something failed, you can search for "dualboot". There are lots of tutorials about your problem.